# Is Durandal getting in the way of my POST to a 3rd party asp.net handler? 405 Method not allowed error

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ckeditor, durandal, asp.net-web-api-routing, roxy-fileman

I've added Roxy Fileman to my project and tied it in to CKEditor.  It's a standard Durandal project with an MVC controller for routing and a web api controller for ajax/json data calls.

A typical working URL for a web api call in my app is `http://localhost:63093/api/DurandalApi/getAssessmentQuestionnairePushMenu?id=1`

When I try and upload a file from within CKEditor, I get:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:63093/fileman/index.html?type=image&CKEditor=ckeditor&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en
Request Method:POST
Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address:[::1]:63093
```

If, however, I directly go to `http://localhost:63093/fileman/index.html?type=image&CKEditor=ckeditor&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en` in my browser, the file upload works perfectly and I can then browse to the image from FileMan inside CKEditor.

The network tab in chrome dev tools indicates that the successful upload is done using this URL: `http://localhost:63093/fileman/asp_net/main.ashx?a=UPLOAD` which is significantly different to the one that CKEditor attampts to use, but that may be because in the second example, index.html is already loaded?

I'm not completely up to speed with what's going on, but the fact that the same URL works perfectly outside of Durandal if I go directly to the URL seems to indicate the FileMan plugin is working just fine and all permissions are set accordingly. Furthermore the CKEditor config is also fine as it can see the images I upload in the directory, but for some reason it's unable to "post" from within CKEditor (which is embedded in a standard Durandal view).

I'm trying to read up on routing to see if I need to do some kind of exception mapping in Durandal to tell it to let the 3rd party .ashx handler deal with the POST request and I'm not even sure if this problem is indicative of Durandal getting in the way or something else. Any suggestions gratefully received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah. All has become clear. This is a half and half answer really as it doesn't really solve the problem, but equally the problem doesn't really exist!

The issue is that Roxy Fileman does NOT use the CK Editor inbuilt "upload" tab that is in the popup. It expects the user to "browse server" only and use the "add file" link in Roxy instead.

I was confused by the instructions, but now I understand!